# Oracle ORA-2291 parent key not found

Tags: oracle

I solve one problem with my Oracle table, but another problem appears. It´s ORA-2291.
I have two tables.
First table:

> ID - Number, Description - NVarchar(150), Filename - NVarchar(150), Binary - BLOB, Thumbnail - BLOB, ORD - Number, ID_ITEMS - Number.
>
> Second table - ID - Number, Name - NVarchar(60), Desc_term - NVArchar(200), ID_Description Number

I have set primary keys on both ids. I have also done foreing key.. From ID_ITEMS to ID in second table. Problem is, when i want to insert image to database, it says - ORA 02291. Any tips? :/

Comment: Please provide the `create table` DDL statements for both tables.

Comment: well the error is obvious you are inserting in the child table (where its foreing key referenced by) where the parent key doesnt have values.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-2291 parent key not found

-> Parent key not found means that you inserted a Key somewhere where no parent key exists.
With the few information you provide I guess you want to insert a record in table 1 with the value `X` in column `ID_ITEMS`. But there is no corresponding element in the table where the foreign key links to, table 2. In table 2 you need a corresponding entry for each `X` in `ID_ITEMS`

```
insert into table2 (ID)
values (1337);
insert into table1 (ID, ID_ITEMS)
values(12321(random id), 1337);
-->WORKS


insert into table1 (ID, ID_ITEMS)
values(12322(random id), 1338); -->Error ORA-2291 Parent key not found
insert into table2 (ID)
values (1338);
-->DOESNT WORK
```

You need to insert the parent key first, as clearly described in the error message.